# how to display the selected item from the selectebox in python and streamlit

Tags: python, dropdown, streamlit

I have a selectbox in the streamlit code where it includes a list of option and what I want is to display the selected item by the user.

The problem is that when the user select whatever item from the list it just displays the first item even if the user changes his selection.

```
import streamlit as st

list_o = ["ac milan", "barsa", "juventus"]
result = st.selectbox("select team", list_o)
st.write(f'the selected team:{result}')
```

It always displays this message :

```
the selected team ac milan
```

Comment: how are you running this script? I ran it as `streamlit run c:\temp\test\test.py` and when the page loads, it will of course display 'the selected team ac milan'. Do you mean it does not change even after you change the selection?

Comment: Yes that is what  i mean exactly

Comment: Sorry, cannot replicate it **with code snippet you have given**. I tried on Microsoft Edge latest and chrome. Perhaps you are trying on some other browser?

Comment: You mean when you try my code it return the selected item each time you change??

Comment: yep. exactly...

Comment: But i am using chrome and i did restart the app several times and still it give the same result.
 Can it be restoring a cashed data ?? Or what ?

Comment: you can try two things: 1. update chrome (maybe it will help) 2. run `streamlit cache clear` see the message you get. There are few bugs reported on streamlit site for little strange behaviour but I don't think they are relevant. If you are windows, if two above don't work,  you can always try rebooting your machine (I know it's extreme but on windows it's always valid thing to do)

Comment: The code works perfectly for me.